# Connectivity of two-layer graph

Tags: graph-theory

My undirected graph has two types of nodes/vertices. Imagine 100 at the top, and 400 at the bottom. The top ones and the bottom ones are connected through vertices. But there are no connections within the top ones or within the bottom ones. Here is a very simple example:

```
T1   T2   T3
|\  /|\   |\
| \/ | \  | \
| /\ |  \ |  \
|/  \|   \|   \
B1   B2   B3  B4
```

What I would like to compute is the number of bottom vertices I have to remove before the graph becomes disjoint, i.e. there is no connection top->bottom->top etc. until all vertices are reached.

The normal vertex connectivity computation gives me the wrong answer, because I could remove T3 and B4 would be alone, but I am not interested in disjoint bottom nodes, only disjoint top nodes.

Any idea how to approach this? I would even be happy with a lower limit on the number of bottom nodes to remove.

Comment: If you add edges between any two bottom nodes that share a neighbor on top, then removing a top node can never contribute to breaking the graph apart, so your "normal vertex connectivity computation" would give you the answer. But if you have top nodes of high degree this could mean adding a lot of edges.

Comment: Aha. Essentially I would hide the top nodes as midpoints of edges and then only consider the bottom nodes as the graph.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. As you suspected, the connectivity computation is very slow because the graph is typically almost complete. I get connectivities of ~25. If you put your comment as answer, I can accept it.